# Check if input file window closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange, file-io

I know when user opens the file input window

```
$("#uploaded_file").click(){function(){ //do something });
```

I know when he selects a file

```
$("#uploaded_file").change(){function(){ //do something });
```

But how I can find if he opened the window and then closed it?

Comment: you can check the value of $("#uploaded_file") on blur event

Comment: @kpsingh when he close the window I want to execute a function but the blur event spamming all the time during file selection so my function will execute multiple times :/